# App.xaml cannot be edited in the Design view

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have been working on a .NET 6 WPF application using Visual Studio 2022 v17.6.5. For some reason, at a random point during development, when I tried to open the `App.xaml` file to add some Dictionaries I started getting this message:

`App.xaml cannot be edited in the Design view.`

[image: screenshot]

Cleaning and rebuilding did not solve the issue.

I can still open and edit the file in other IDEs or text editors, but not in Visual Studio.

I have looked on the Internet to see if this was a common issue and I could not find anything useful. Does anyone know what's causing this and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The issue is that `App.xaml` doesn not contain any View. It's just basic configuration for the other Xaml resources. You can open it in the XAML editor

Comment: I have tried this already, right click on App.xaml > Open with... > XAML Designer.
Tried the other options too (Automatic Editor Selectro, XAML Designer with Encoding).

Comment: What do you expect to see in the Designer? The App.xaml does not contain a UserControl or Window.

Comment: Up until this point I was able to open and edit the App.xaml file normally in Visual Studio (just like you would edit a ResourceDictionary).
I don't know if the file was previously being opened in the XAML Designer or any other parser/viewer/component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you accidentally closed Enable XAML Designer(requires restart of Visual Studio)

Here's the App.xaml that opens when Enable XAML Designer is closed (requires restart of Visual Studio):

[image]

Please follow the steps below to enable Enable XAML Designer (requires restart of Visual Studio):

Tools => Options => XAML Designer => General => Check Enable XAML Designer(requires restart of Visual Studio)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the XAML designer was already enabled, and I had been able to edit app.xaml earlier in the lifetime of my project.  I restored the entire solution folder from a week-old backup, opened the offending project, and was able to edit the file.  Restored again from a backup taken earlier the same day, again no problem.

I had been restoring to a different folder from where the solution lives.  When I copied the restored solution folder to the normal solution folder, I was again unable to open app.xaml.  So the exact same solution folder behaved differently depending on what it’s parent folder is.

I searched the solution folder for files containing the solution folder path and name, and in addition to various .dll, .cache, and .iref files, it was present in the .suo file.

I deleted the .suo file.  After it recreated itself the next time VS was started, I was able to open and edit app.xaml with no issues.

Comment: This is a very wordy answer, when the core of the solution is in the last paragraph.

Comment: Answer is too wordy

Comment: Sorry about the wordiness.  I thought perhaps the different behaviors exhibited when the solution was restored to different folders might be helpful to someone.